# Cryptocurrency is not viable for mass-market application?

Tags: ether, gas, wallets, dapps, dapp-development

**The Idea**

I am new to cryptocurrency. I am writing an app/game that has its own marketplace for digital items. I have an established userbase of around 120,000 users of which 6,000 are paying customers currently.  I expect this to grow 10x with a new feature and marketplace. **These users are laymen to crypto.**

Historically, apps would just make their own fake virtual currency (non-crypto) that could only be used in-game only. Users would trade fiat money for this virtual currency to purchase in-game virtual items.

My idea allows for people to sell virtual items in-game and I want to allow them to take the earnings they made in-game and be able to trade it back to fiat-money. Either through my website (via an API) or through popular exchanges. To make the process easier for the laymen I would offer a built-in wallet on my site tied to their account.

I prefer to defer all the tax ramifications to the users, and the buying and selling of the coin to a third party. I am not looking to profit off them exchanging fiat for currency (or vice versa), and I prefer as hands-off as possible. I want them to own their money (fiat or virtual) and have no say in it.

I prefer a stablecoin because then people won't be concerned (as much) about instability compared to fiat.

**What are my options?**

---

**My research**

It seems the best choice for a stable coin is "DAI" but the transaction time is high and the gas fee is too high. There is "xDAI" but it seems to really complicate the process of buying and it would be very painful to get customers new to crypto to be able to manage a wallet and have to learn how to bridge.

In terms of a platform, [enjin.io](https://enjin.io) meets my needs perfectly. I really wish it was based on a stablecoin though.

**Is there any coin based on ERC-1155 that is also stable?  if not, is there a way to make a ERC-1155 coin that is stable?** Ideally I'd want to use [jumpnet](https://enjin.io/blog/jumpnet) as soon as I could too.

---

**Breakdown**

There are 6 wants for a currency;

1. Limited KYC (know-your-customer) required to purchase with less than 2% fee
2. Stablecoin tied to fiat money
3. Protocol supports fungible (selling copies of 1 thing) and non-fungible (unique copy)
4. Smart contracts  (if someone re-sells the asset then a % goes back to the original content creator automatically, etc)
5. Low gas fees
6. Easy to transfer to bank or back to fiat

**DAI** meets  2, 3, 4, 6

**xDAI** meets 2, 3, 4, 5

**enjin** meets 3, 4, 6

**enjin (with jumpnet)** meets 3, 4, 5

I think number 1 is a lost cause when it comes to crypto, unless I mitigate the risk myself and become a minter or an exchange myself. This could be feasible in bulk but I'd prefer not to.

---

**Conclusion**

Is cryptocurrency really not a viable option yet (legally, laymen abstraction) for a company to start a virtual marketplace and have their users own their money?

I feel like my best option is to go with a fake currency and then have to manage sending out form w-9 to everyone who wants to exchange back to fiat, rather than users managing their own money.

Comment: You would have more chances by asking that on Reddit, use case design questions are usually not expected here.